# Guzzle custom handler that switches to another host on failure

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

I need to create a sort of High Availability Guzzle 6 client which, given a list of 3 hosts, falls back to sending its requests on the next one when the current one is down / does not respond.

This functionality has to be built in the Client object. I was told I needed to use a [custom handler](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/6.5/handlers-and-middleware.html), but can't understand how to do it.

Comment: I'm not conviced that guzzle is the best way to do loadBalancing. Why not using a haProxy in front of your 3 hosts and connect guzzle to it ?

Comment: I just need it in a Guzzle Client. This is a requirement.